# I'm trying to write a python based keyboard&mouse cursor macro

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

people of Stackoverflow! I've just started my coding journey and this seems like the problem that makes me want to give it all up already xD
I'm sorry if this is something easy but I really tried out everything I possibly could

I am trying to write a macro that will remember the position of the cursor on the screen with the ctrl key, and return the cursor to that position with the alt key.

```
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl_l:
        print(pyautogui.position()) 

    with open("cf.py", "a") as f:
        with redirect_stdout(f):
            print((pyautogui.position()))
```

everything works pretty well untill I try to get the output results from the cf.py to the main file so I can use them in the alt macro.

```
    from cf import Point

    if key == keyboard.Key.alt_l:
       print(pyautogui.moveTo(Point(x, y)))

    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a great way of doing things. You should be *reading* the position from a file, rather than *importing* the file. There are multiple ways of doing this, but this will probably be the easiest:

```
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard
import json

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl_l:
        print(pyautogui.position()) 

    with open("cf.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(list(pyautogui.position()), f)


    if key == keyboard.Key.alt_l:
       with open("cf.json") as f:
           x, y = json.load(f)
       pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)

    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea I could use json for this, and it seems like a really convinient way of solving this type of tasks! Could I please ask you for one more bit of help, everything's fine except when I press alt_l pycharm outputs "None" and I really don't know what causes this

Comment: You're welcome. Mark the question as answered if you're satisfied with my answer.

Comment: `print(pyautogui.moveTo(x, y))` is the culprit, moveTo doesn't return a value, ie. returns a `None`, if you remove the print statement it shouldn't output anything. I edited my answer so it should work as expected now.